# Execution failed for task ':react-native-custom-tabs:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebugAndroidTest'

Tags: android, react-native, gradle, detox

I am trying to build ./gralde assembleAndroidTest and the result is an error

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

> What went wrong:
>
> Execution failed for task ':react-native-custom-tabs:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebugAndroidTest'.
>
> java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException:
>   com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Unable to merge
>   dex

Following is my project gradle details:

**app/build.gradle**

```
androidTestImplementation(project(path: ":detox"))
androidTestImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:rules:1.0.1'
ext {
    supportLibVersion = "27.0.2"
    playServicesVersion = "11.8.0"
    reactNativeVersion = "0.53.3"
}
```

**android/build.gradle:**

```
ext {
    compileSdkVersion = 27
    buildToolsVersion = "27.0.2"
    targetSDKVersion = 27
    minSDKVersion = 21
}
```

**react-native-custome-tabs/build.gradle:**

```
android {
        compileSdkVersion 25
        buildToolsVersion "25.0.1"

        defaultConfig {
            minSdkVersion 16
            targetSdkVersion 23
            versionCode 1
            versionName "1.0"
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        compile "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"  
        compile 'com.android.support:customtabs:25.0.1'
        compile ('com.github.droibit.customtabslauncher:launcher:1.0.8') {
        exclude module: 'customtabs'
        }
        testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
        }
```

I am getting conflict error message in both build.gradle

[image: app/build.gradle screenshot]
[image: react-native-customtab/build.gradle screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

Use `compile 'com.android.support:customtabs:23.0.1'`

Comment: changed `implementation ('com.android.support:design:27.0.2') {
        force = true;
    }` under app/build.gradle also changed compile 'com.android.support:customtabs:25.0.1' under customtabs/build.gradle. However, error goes of but new error coiming                                                               
  >Execution failed for task ':react-native-custom-tabs:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.

Comment: idea is you need to use same version number for support libs.

Comment: and your compileSdkVersion 25 so your com.android.support:design should have version according to that.

Comment: under which build.gradle do i need to change compileSdkVersion?

Comment: react-native-custome-tabs/build.gradle:

Comment: Amit, Not able to resolve, I have created git repo, if you can help https://github.com/neerajlad/Detox-React-Native-Custom-Tab